# How do you point to an object without affect it upon deletion?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```
struct object
{
   char* whatever;
}
struct other_object
{
   object** points;
   int number;
}

void add_to_points(other_object* passer, const struct object* object_ptr)
{
   passer->points[passer->number] = object_ptr; //leads to warning
   number++;
}

void delete_memory(other_object* passer)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < passer->numbers; i++){
      free(passer->points[i]);
   }
}

struct object* new_object = malloc(sizeof(object));
struct other_object* new_object_2 = malloc(sizeof(other_object));
new_object_2->points = malloc(3*sizeof(object));

add_to_points(new_object_2, new_object);
delete_memory(new_object_2);
```

So with the above code, it seems like delete_memory is actually freeing the object itself. I know this may have to do with my add_to_points function, but I'm not clear on how to change it so that "points" only points to the object, but if we delete a member of points (such as points[2]) or the whole thing all together, the object itself isn't destroyed.

Comment: `passer->points[i] = 0;`?

Comment: What makes you think `delete_memory` is freeing "the object itself"? Which object is that, anyway? Also, this code has several errors that would prevent it from compiling, which means it probably doesn't reflect your real problem accurately enough for us to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call malloc for `new_object_2->points` with `object*` instead `object`. You seem to want achive array of pointers to object instead of array of object as you did.

Replace

```
new_object_2->points = malloc(3*sizeof(object));
```

with

```
new_object_2->points = malloc(3*sizeof(object*));
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, because `sizeof(object)` and `sizeof(object*)` have the same value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
void add_to_points(other_object* passer, struct object* object_ptr)
{
    if (passer->number < 3) {
        passer->points[passer->number] = object_ptr; //leads to warning
        (passer->number)++;
    }
}
```

you use a wrong `number` variable in `add_to_points`. `passer->number` would be correct. also don't forget to initialize this variable after the `malloc`. Also you should first test it to be smaller than `3` before writing something into `passer->points[passer->number]`. The warning comes from the `const` in the parameter list.

Comment: I've edited my code above. When I call delete_memory, the object, new_object, seems to be freed as well. If I try to call, say, free(object->whatever) afterwards (assuming object->whatever was malloc(5*sizeof(char)); my program crashes.

Comment: can you make a MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You only have edited one occurence of `number` in the function.